# magento product grid with 4 columns only on 1 column template

Tags: magento, layout

i want to make product listing page to use 4 columns instead of 3 (default)
I found that if i use

```
<reference name="product_list">
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
</reference>
```

on category layout update (from backend) it's working fine. I also found numerous posts that describes on how to make 4 columns grid for all page layouts.

I need to use 4 column grid only on one column pages. i put this on my local.xml but it's not working..

```
<page_one_column>
     <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
    </reference>
</page_one_column>
```

what am i doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 2):

go to admin

2) catalog->manage categories

3) select category which you want to be one colomn layout in my example **cell phone**

4) click on custom design

5)

```
Use Parent Category Settings = no

Page Layout = 1 column
Custom Layout Update 

<reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
    </reference>
```

hope this help
[image]1)

**or Alternate solution**

app/design/frontend/default/[yourtheme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

line no 89

```
 <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
```

replace above code  with

```
 <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $pageLayout=$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate(); ?>
    <?php if ($pageLayout="page/1column.phtml"):?>
        <?php $_columnCount = 4 ?>
    <?php else: ?>  
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Edit: stack does not let me edit my previous comment.. As i said the "custom design" method is not useful for me because i need this for all 1 column layout.. The alternate solution with code edit could work, but i wanted to do it with layout xml. That was also the purpose of my question.. If it is impossible to do what i need with only xml update i will do the php method you provide. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

open **app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml**

define column count according to your requirement

in

```
<catalog_category_default>,<catalog_category_layered>
```

**or**

if yout want to set column count in `<catalogsearch_result_index>`

open and edit in

open `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml`

```
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
```

now define observer in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
```

add following code in `<events>`

```
    <catalog_controller_category_init_after>
          <observers>
                <custom_page_layout>
                    <class>catalog/observer</class>
                         <method>addHandle</method>
                </custom_page_layout>
           </observers>
  </catalog_controller_category_init_after>
```

now open

```
 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php
```

add following function it

```
public function addHandle($observer)
    {
        $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
        if ($category->getPageLayout()) {
                $controllerAction->getLayout()->helper('page/layout')
                    ->applyHandle($category->getPageLayout());
            }
    }
```

go to admin

2) catalog->manage categories

3) select category which you want to be one column layout

4) click on custom design

5) Use Parent Category Settings = no
   Page Layout = 1 column

Note: instead of edit in core create new module & define above observer

hope this help you

Comment: is it possible to do it with just layout upadate, without editing (overriding) any core code? just with local.xml or something..

Comment: it is not possible without change or override in core files

Comment: local.xml is used for layout purpose not for configuration or settings
. Or you can create module & define above code in that